# How to have Range condition in VLOOKUP?

Tags: excel

I have the below table in Excle file and i want to find the value column for the respective input.

```
Col A   Col B   Col C   Min  Max    Value
101      AA      High   0    10   1%
101      AA      High   11   20   2%
101      AA      Low    0    10   3%
101      AA      Low    11   20   4%
101      BB      High   0    10   5%
101      BB      High   11   20   6%
101      BB      Low    0    10   7%
101      BB      Low    11   20   8%
```

For the input 101, AA, Low, 12 - i should get 4%
I have already tried Formula Array and it is working great, however the prerformnace is not so good and hence i wanted to move away. Also i dont want to use DSUM or VBA. I want do achieve in plain Excel formula. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no duplicate rows, you can use following formulas:

for Excel 2007 or later:

```
=SUMIFS(F2:F9,A2:A9,101,B2:B9,"AA",C2:C9,"Low",D2:D9,"<="&12,E2:E9,">="&12)
```

for Excel 2003:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((F2:F9)*(A2:A9=101)*(B2:B9="AA")*(C2:C9="Low")*(D2:D9<=12)*(E2:E9>=12))
```

where `101`, `"AA"`, `"Low"` and `12` could be changed to cell references (e.g. `G1`,`G2` and so on)

[image]

Comment: Hi Simoco.. Thanks. I tried this and works great.. however if the F columns in non numeric. Is there a way to handle?

Comment: Also this fails if i put "12" in the last condition. it returns zero

Comment: 1) no, it works only if `F` column is numeric, 2) why it should returns something if there is no value `12` in `Min` column?

Comment: `Min and Max is the range value if my value falls in between the range` - see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

If you use this version it can return text or number - if there's no match you get #N/A

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:A9=101)/(B2:B9="AA")/(C2:C9="Low")/(D2:D9=11),F2:F9)`

If there is more than one matching row that returns the **last** - for the **first** try this version:

`=INDEX(F2:F9,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2:A9=101)*(B2:B9="AA")*(C2:C9="Low")*(D2:D9=11),0),0))`

Comment: Sorry if i was not clear.. the main reason for this question is to have a Range lookup. Min and Max is the range value if my value falls in between the range .. i want to get the respective value

Comment: @Sathish, it's not a problem, you can use `=LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:A9=101)/(B2:B9="AA")/(C2:C9="Low")/(D2:D9<=11)/(E2:E9>=11),F2:F9)` instead