# Looking for a function similar to SUMIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, the `SUMIFS` function is great for creating a summation occurrences where multiple conditions on multiple ranges are met. However, I am looking for a similar function, that returns *the first value where these conditions are met*. For instance, a table contains a column with first names, a columns with surnames, and a column with User IDs. Given the first name and surname, I need to look up the person's User ID.

Is there a formula for this? I have tried searching all kinds of combinations with "if" and "ifs", but to no avail. I do not want to write a macro for something so simple.

Comment: I think this answer is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059534/how-to-have-range-condition-in-vlookup/23059914#23059914

Answer (score 0):

Though you would prefer not to write a macro for something simple like this, in this case I would say that this is the simplest solution. A short function like this would be useful, if you decide to employ this type of technique down the road at some point:

```
Function FindRowIndex(firstName As String, lastName As String) As Integer      
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheet1
        For j = 1 To NumLines
            If .Cells(j, 1) = firstName And .Cells(j, 2) = lastName Then
                FindRowIndex = j
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next j
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

this works...

```
=INDEX(C1:C9,SUMPRODUCT((A1:A9=A10)*(B1:B9=B10)*ROW(1:9)))
```

the following picture shows it in position... https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFaC9.png

this picture shows the result you require... https://i.stack.imgur.com/Id0BZ.png

obviously if you need more than 9 rows just adjust the 4 references within the formula.