# How to vlookup multiple cells in a row?

Tags: excel, pivot, vlookup

I have two pivot tables . I need to vlookup income values from table1 based on values that i have in table2. The goal is to populate column `Q` .  The unique identifier of a row in both tables consists of `team, state , person` . Therefore in order to `vlookup` i use `concatenate`

[image]

Here is the formula that i use for the `K` column values `=TRIM(CONCATENATE(TRIM(G2), TRIM(H2), TRIM(I2)))`

Here is the formula that I use for the `Q` column values `=VLOOKUP(TRIM(CONCATENATE(TRIM(M2), TRIM(N2),TRIM(O2))),$G$2:$K$40,4,FALSE)`

It works fine only for `totals` . Why doesn't it work for other values ? How should I improve my formulas ?

Comment: try `=INDEX($J$2:$J$40,MATCH(TRIM(M2) & TRIM(N2) & TRIM(O2),TRIM($G$2:$G$40) & TRIM($H$2:$H$40) & TRIM($I$2:$I$40),0))` and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to evaluate formula

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and got `error in value `

Comment: have you pressed  CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER  to evaluate formula?

Comment: Yes. I tried . I works nice. But in case there is no match I get `N\A` . I tried `=if(iserror(INDEX($J$2:$J$40,MATCH(TRIM(M2) & TRIM(N2) & TRIM(O2),TRIM($G$2:$G$40) & TRIM($H$2:$H$40) & TRIM($I$2:$I$40),0))),0,=INDEX($J$2:$J$40,MATCH(TRIM(M2) & TRIM(N2) & TRIM(O2),TRIM($G$2:$G$40) & TRIM($H$2:$H$40) & TRIM($I$2:$I$40),0)))`

Comment: try `=IFERROR(INDEX($J$2:$J$40,MATCH(TRIM(M2) & TRIM(N2) & TRIM(O2),TRIM($G$2:$G$40) & TRIM($H$2:$H$40) & TRIM($I$2:$I$40),0)),0)` with  CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: I got it now . THANK YOU!!! PLEASE ANSWER TO THIS equestion so that i could accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, you can use:

```
=INDEX($J$2:$J$40,MATCH(TRIM(M2) & TRIM(N2) & TRIM(O2),TRIM($G$2:$G$40) & TRIM($H$2:$H$40) & TRIM($I$2:$I$40),0))
```

This is an *array formula*, so type the formula then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Curly brackets will automatically appear at the start and end of the formula.

Or more elegant approach (similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059534/how-to-have-range-condition-in-vlookup/23059914#23059914)):

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(TRIM($G$2:$G$40)=TRIM(M2))/(TRIM($H$2:$H$40)=TRIM(N2))/(TRIM($I$2:$I$40)=TRIM(O2)),$J$2:$J$40)
```

above formula is normal (not array) formula

Comment: For the `lookup` approach to work, the data should be sorted in an ascending order , right ?

Comment: no, there is special trick here:) you're searching `2` in array of `{#DIV0!,#DIV0!,1,#DIV0!,#DIV0!..}` and `LOOKUP` always returns position of `1` in array (which indicates that all conditions are meet)